# Is there a nice way to create "split object" in C++?

Tags: c++, embedded

First of all let me say that I'm creating software for microcontrollers, so RAM usage matters and it makes sense to put large blocks of const data to non-volatile (flash) memory.

What I'm trying to achieve is to find a nice way to create a "split" object in C++. As an example let's assume that there's one byte of data (read/write) and a multibyte "receipt" for accessing it. Let's say that the "receipt" is a long string that is a filename, and the media that it points to is slow, so it makes sense to buffer the single byte in memory, instead of actually reading it on each request.

```
class Data
{
    uint8_t byte;
    bool valid;
    const char filename[128];
    uint8_t read()
    {
        if (!valid)
            performReallySlowRead(filename, &byte);
        valid = true;
        return byte;
    };
    void write(uint8_t new_value)
    {
        byte = new_value;
        performRealWriteToMedia(filename, byte);
        valid = true;
    };
}
```

The obvious problem with this approach is that whole 130-bytes end up in RAM, while only two of them need to be changed. So I've come up with an idea of split-object:

```
class DataNonConst
{
    uint8_t byte;
    bool valid;
}

class DataConst
{
    const char filename[128];
    DataNonConst * const data;
}

static DataNonConst storage;
const DataConst holder("some_long_name_here", &storage);
```

Now the only problem is that if I would like to have a few hundred of such split-objects the process of creating them (so creating TWO objects and linking second to first) gets pretty boring and problematic...

So the question is - is there some nice way to make it easier to use, preferably a clever-C++-trick or maybe some template magic? That is - how to create TWO objects, linked together, with a single statement, preferably one object is hidden? I don't think macro-solution is possible here, as there's no easy way to automate creation of the name for storage object... The objects need to be of same type, as I need to embed pointers to such objects in other places (one function deals with writing them, other only cares about reading)... All the solutions that I've thought of either require use of virtual interface to templates (so you make the object bigger by vtable pointer AND probably get a bonus template-bloat) or result in huge template bloat...

**EDIT:**

Actually part of the whole problem can be reduced to a simplier question - is there a way to "bind" an anonymous variable to a member field in C++? Sth like:

```
const ConstData holder("...", NonConstData()); // this object HAS TO be ROMable
```

In the above "wishful thinking" holder is const object in ROM and it has a pointer/reference/whatever to an anonymous object NonConstData created "somewhere" in RAM.
Or:

```
std:pair<const ConstData &, NonConstData &> holder(ConstData(), NonConstData());
```

Anything that would allow me NOT to manually create both objects and bind one to another.

Comment: What for constancy in holder required?

Comment: To make it ROMable so that it would be placed in non-volatile memory, not in RAM. This is very important for the subject...

Comment: Regarding the macro solution -- couldn't you pass in the name of the storage object as an argument to the macro?

Comment: haven't thought of that - thx! Anyway - it's not far from creating such object manually...

Comment: "create two objects, linked together, with a single statement, preferably one object is hidden?" Which one would you like to be hidden, the `storage` or the `holder?` I assume it's the `storage`, right?

Comment: right - all the access to the "split-object" goes through holder (the const part), which has a pointer to RAM storage. The storage does not need to be hidden, but if there's a simple way to achieve that - why not (;

Answer (score 2):

You can replace a pointer with an integer, and create a single static array for all your `DataNonConst` objects, like this:

```
class DataNonConst {
    uint8_t byte;
    bool valid;
};

static DataNonConst storages[MAX_DATA];

class DataConst {
    const char filename[128];
    const int dataIndex;
    DataNonConst *data() {
        return &storages[dataIndex];
    }
};

const DataConst holderOne("first_long_name_here", 0);
const DataConst holderTwo("second_long_name_here", 1);
const DataConst holderThree("third_long_name_here", 2);
```

This approach is inspired by the [*Flyweight Pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern), although obviously it's used for a different purpose here.

An obvious downside to this is that you need to count your entries manually to avoid duplication. However, there is only one `storages` object, so there's nothing else to create.

Comment: How is this better than having a pointer to the DataNonConst in the DataConst object?  You still need to touch flash to get at what's in ram.

Comment: @dspeyer - access to underlying storage should go through const holder object which is in flash - nothing wrong about that

Answer (score 2):

As far as I see, the only issue here is that your "Handle" object has a `char[]` member.  I bet if you replace that with a `const char*`, that solves your issues, since string literals are probably in the non-volatile memory anyway.

```
class Data
{
    const char* filename;
    uint8_t byte;
    bool valid;
    Data(const char* filename_) : filename(filename_), valid(false) {}
    uint8_t read()
    {
        if (!valid)
            performReallySlowRead(filename, &byte);
        valid = true;
        return byte;
    };
    void write(uint8_t new_value)
    {
        byte = new_value;
        performRealWriteToMedia(filename, byte);
        valid = true;
    };
};

Data holder("some_long_name_here"); //name is in the non-volatile memory anyway

char buffer[128] = "\var\bin\omg";
Data holder2(buffer); //runtime names work fine, but have to manage the storage yourself.
```

Or, if you want to be crafty, you can make this a template and save even that amount of memory (at the expense of being *slightly* more confusing.  This has the added benefit of being able to easily add `static` members, which will also be in non-volatile memory, but not shared per filename.  It's not obvious, but this *can* be used with files whos names are not known at runtime, but I don't recommend doing that.

```
template<const char* filename>
class Data
{
    uint8_t byte;
    bool valid;
    uint8_t read()
    {
        if (!valid)
            performReallySlowRead(filename, &byte);
        valid = true;
        return byte;
    };
    void write(uint8_t new_value)
    {
        byte = new_value;
        performRealWriteToMedia(filename, byte);
        valid = true;
    };
};
Data<"some_long_name_here"> holder;

extern char buffer[128] = "\var\bin\omg";
A<buffer> holder2; //this always refers to the filename currently in buffer
```

However, if you *really* want a split object, your what you have as the split suggestion is really the best answer I can think of.

Comment: unfortunatelly the "filename" is just an example (; In your solution the pointer to filename gets stored in RAM, but for the sake of this discussion let's assume that each byte of memory counts, that's why it has to be split and that's why the const one points to non-const part, not the other way around.

Comment: @FreddieChopin: Yes, in my first sample, the _pointer_ to the filename is in RAM.  If every byte counts, use the template example.  That keeps only the needed bits in RAM.

Comment: Your answer made me thinking about move semantics and rvalue references of C++11. Would something like that be possible to use here? For example constructor to DataConst would take a rvalue reference to DataNonConst:
DataNonConst holder(DataConst());
would sth like that be possible?

Comment: @FreddieChopin: Unfortunately, no.  The `DataConst()` would be destroyed right away.  If you want it to be in ROM, it needs to be a global.

Comment: Now I got that mixed - it should be the other way around - DataConst holder(DataNonConst()) - the constructor would take rvalue reference.

Comment: @FreddieChopin either way, C++ will destroy the unnamed parameter right away

Comment: but when using move semantics it should not be destroyed, right? I'd like to achieve something similar to the string example - when function takes pointer, the compiler "magically" creates the string object and gives you the pointer. I thought move semantics and rvalue references allowed you to do similar thing with user objects?

Comment: @FreddieChopin: Move semantics would move the `DataNonConst` into the constructor, and then if the `DataConst` construstor doesn't store it somewhere, it will be destroyed when the constructor finishes.  Sorry, but move semantics are not really related to the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: but the constructor would store that rvalue, I just cannot make it to be ROMable /;

Comment: @FreddieChopin: That's true, but that would require the ROM side to allocate change itself to assign a pointer to a `new DataNonConst` from the temporary.  Obviously, that can't work at all.  `DataConst` would have to have a line like `DataNonCostPtr = new DataNonConst(param);`, but such a line would mean it couldn't be in ROM.  If it were as easy as you suggest, my answer would have mentioned that.

Answer (score 2):

With some restrictions, you can leverage templates to create a static instance of DataNonConst that is referenced by each ROMable DataConst objects.

Restrictions:

- The code uses the `__LINE__` macro and thus there must only be one DataConst declaration per line. Alternatively, if the `__COUNT__`
  macro is available, it can be used in place of `__LINE__` to allow
  multiple declarations per line.
- The `DataNonConst` objects are always zero-initialized.

Code:

```
struct DataNonConst
{
    uint8_t byte;
    bool valid;
};

struct DataConst
{
    const char filename[128];
    DataNonConst * const data;
};

namespace {

template <long n>
struct DataNonConstHolder
{
    static DataNonConst data;
};

template <long n> DataNonConst DataNonConstHolder<n>::data;

}

// If __COUNT__ macro is supported, use it instead of __LINE__
#define Initializer(s) { s, &DataNonConstHolder<__LINE__>::data }

const DataConst dc1 = Initializer("filename1");
const DataConst dc2 = Initializer("filename2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply declare the `const` members `static const`.

`static` members are be stored separately from the object instance data in any case.  Your compiler may automatically place `static const` such members in ROM, but if not there are likely to be compiler directives that will force that.

Comment: const elements for each split-object have to be different, so it cannot be static const.

Comment: @FreddieChopin:  The fact remains that non-static const members are unlikley to be located in ROM due to the semantics of `const` in C++ where const members my be run-time initialised.  You could use multiple classes containing only static const data members and derive classes from them as necessary with the non-const data in the subclass.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to have a maximum count of objects, you can use indices as implicit pointers:

```
class Data;
Data *dataArray;
char **filenameArray;

class Data {
  uint8_t byte;
  bool valid;
  char*& filename() {
    int index = this - dataArray;
    return filenameArray[index];
  }
 public:
  byte read() {
    if (!valid)
      performReallySlowRead(filename(), &byte);
    valid = true;
    return byte;
  }
  init(char* fn) {
    filename() = allocateInFlash(strlen(fn));
    strdup(filename(), fn);
    valid = FALSE;
  }
};

// Somewhere before things get run
dataArray = allocateInRam(sizeof(Data)*nDatas);
filenameArray = allocateInFlash(sizeof(char*)*nDatas);
```

This means you don't need any overhead, and you don't need to touch flash to read from ram.  You also no longer use standard memory management, which could be a plus or a minus.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to have some purely flash overhead, you could do:

```
class Data;
std::map<Data*,string, less<Data*>, FlashAllocator<pair<Data*,string>> fns;
class Data {
  uint8_t byte;
  bool valid;
 public:
  byte read(){
    if (!valid)
      performReallySlowRead(fns[this],&byte);
    valid = true;
    return byte;
  }
  Data(string fn) {
    fns[this] = fn;
  }
  ~Data() {
    fns.erase(this);
  }
};
```

Maps have nontrivial overhead, but it's all in flash.

Comment: Do I see correctly that flash would need to be writable at runtime?

Comment: @FreddieChopin Yes.  Flash generally is, right?  If not, then where are the filenames coming from?

Comment: if you think "flash" as an SD card then sure - it's writable, but here "flash" == "code read-only memory". It's also writable, but that's not so easy - the idea is to create the objects at compile-time.